# Passing UserId value to another table after Sign Up

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, userid

My scenario is, when the user is finished creating its account in the CreateUserWizard I want to pass the value of UserId to another table in my database.

I'm using ASP .Net C#.

I've tried the code below but there is an error:  cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to 'byte[]'

Any suggestions for a possible/alternate solutions?

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

Guid currentUserId;
currentUserId = new Guid("{" + currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()+ "}");
MyDataSetTableAdapters.MEMBERINFOTableAdapter accUpdate = new Project1.PAGES.MyTableAdapters.MEMBERINFOTableAdapter();
accUpdate.UpdateQuery(instName, accountMade, lblTodaysDate, currentUserId, instName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this it will help you understand more about asp.net and how to store more infomation

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks Micah for your quick response. However, I'm using a RAW data type for the UserID on my database since I'm using the Oracle database and it gives me an error : cannot convert string to byte[]

Comment: so is this a Oracle Question ?

Comment: No. It's a MySQL question and I just convert to Oracle for my own way of learning. Anyway I found the solution already from the link you posted. Thanks!